# Postgres Trigger Function - Dynamic table name with audit additional data insert

Tags: postgresql, triggers, format, execute, audit

New Postgres user, exploring trigger functions comparing to Oracle. Trying to write a general trigger that takes table name (and schema name if possible) as input and insert audit data into a corresponding audit table. However running into errors. Below is one of the sample code I tried...
tried format as well but still got the error when try to pass additional parameters in audit tables
Any help/input appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_function_tr()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    input_table_name text;
    my_action  char(1);
begin
   input_table_name := 'employee.'||TG_ARGV\[0\];  -- audit table in different schema
   IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
      my_action  := 'I';
   elseif TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
      my_action := 'D';
   else
      my_action := 'U';
   END IF;
   end if;  
   EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO '|| input_table_name ||
'VALUES ' || (my_action,current_user, now(), row_to_json(old));
   IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' then
      RETURN OLD;
   ELSE
      RETURN NEW;
   end if;
END;
$function$
;
```

get below error when trigger is called:

```
SQL Error \[42601\]: ERROR: syntax error at end of input
Where: PL/pgSQL function audit_function_tr() line 16 at EXECUTE
ERROR: syntax error at end of input
Where: PL/pgSQL function audit_function_tr() line 16 at EXECUTE
ERROR: syntax error at end of input
Where: PL/pgSQL function audit_function_tr() line 16 at EXECUTE
```

Comment: Why this `TG_ARGV\[0\]`?

Comment: I originally tried passing a parameter as target tablename and defined trigger function with input parameter as audit_function_tr (tablename text) RETURNS trigger... but then learned I can't declare input parameter and still read it from t_argv array

Comment: 1) Still does not explain why you are doing the escaping `\`? 2) 2) Reformatted code, indentation is good:). Noticed possible error with  the `IF ` conditionals. Seems there is an extra `END IF;`

Comment: 1) Is `TG_ARGV[0]` supposed to be fetching the table name of the table the trigger is working on or another table? If the current table then look at TG_TABLE_NAME here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). 2) Also for something similar that I do I set up a table that maps the trigger table to the audit table and I just run a query to find the appropriate audit table. Then I don't have to update trigger code, just change entries in a table.

Comment: audit is written to a separate table & schema, which stores additional data such as user, timestamp, action. Audit table name is passed with trigger function call.  First time posting and I had to format the code for this site which may have created escape characters...code does compile but gets runtime error. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are falling prey to plain SQL injection. You have to escape your JSON values properly:

```
EXECUTE format(
           'INSERT INTO employee.%I VALUES (%L, %L, %L, %L)',
           TG_ARGV[0],
           my_action,
           current_user,
           now(),
           row_to_json(old)
        );
```

Comment: Thanks. did not work... "U" was for update of record... SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "U"
  Where: PL/pgSQL function audit_function_pg() line 19 at EXECUTE
  ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "U"

Comment: Well, then for god's sake specify a column list with the `INSERT` statement as you always should do. I cannot help you with that, since I don't know the table definition.